# PortAudio library not found by sounddevice

Tags: python, python-sounddevice

I have been working with a python program which uses `sounddevice` module to play audio. The program works fine in my office pc (running **Ubuntu 17.10**), but not in my home pc (running **Linux Mint 18.3**). It generates the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...path/to/my/code.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sounddevice as sd
  File "/home/arif/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sounddevice.py", line 64, in <module>
    raise OSError('PortAudio library not found')
OSError: PortAudio library not found
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you install PortAudio? See [the documentation](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.10/#requirements).

Comment: @Matthias Yes, everything was installed accordingly. I've just noticed that, my script is running on Jupyter Notebook but not on PyCharm.

Comment: The `sounddevice` module does this: `from ctypes.util import find_library; find_library('portaudio')`. If this returns `None`, your error appears.

Comment: I figured that too. Can you point out any reason why is it returning `None`?

Comment: If you figured that, you should probably mention it in your updated question. As for why it might be returning `None`, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#finding-shared-libraries).

Answer (score 85):

I could fix this by installing the portaudio library.

```
sudo apt-get install libportaudio2
```

You may also try following if this doesn't help.

```
sudo apt-get install libasound-dev
```

Comment: The first one fixes the issues on ubuntu 19.4

Comment: what does the second line do?  Is it a dependency?  I didn't see that package listed when I ran the first line.

Comment: I think the second line has to do with numpy installations not working properly on raspberry pis.  Numpy came with sounddevice, but these instructions say that second line is required to fix a numpy problem:  `https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/troubleshooting-importerror.html`

Comment: fix in wsl2 as well

Answer (score 1):

I have Rocky Linux 9, which is based on RHEL. I also fixed that by installing the portaudio package via this command:

```
dnf install portaudio portaudio-devel
```

It might be useful for Rocky Linux users.