# PortAudio library not found by sounddevice during runtime [WINDOWS]

Tags: python, portaudio, python-sounddevice

**PROBLEM:**
Similar to [this question for Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49333582/portaudio-library-not-found-by-sounddevice), I'm running into a `OSError: PortAudio library not found` after I package my app with `pyinstaller` and execute the `.exe`. (Note, I do not encounter any issues when running my unpackaged app via shell. This only happens when I package it with pyinstaller).

Although installing `portaudio` via package manager seems to work for Linux, this doesn't seem to be an option for Windows, since the [sounddevice docs](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.10/#requirements) say, "If you are using Mac OS X or Windows, the library will be installed automagically with pip" and doing a `pip search portaudio` only returns wrappers

**QUESTION**
What do I need to do to get `sounddevice` to work in my Windows environment?
Why does it work in my shell, but not after packaging the app?

**FULL ERROR:**

```
(venv) λ my-app.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 71, in <module>
OSError: PortAudio library not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "point-of-service-recorder.py", line 11, in <module>
    import sounddevice as sd
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "c:\path\to\my\app\venv\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\sounddevice.py", line 83, in <module>
OSError: cannot load library 'C:\Users\TYLER~1.HIT\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI250242\_sounddevice_data\portaudio-binaries\libportaudio32bit.dll': error 0x7e
[23156] Failed to execute script point-of-service-recorder
```

**BUILD OUTPUT**

- Selected output from running pyinstaller build:

```
[...]

22251 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
22260 INFO: Cannot get manifest resource from non-PE file c:\users\path\to\app\venv\lib\site-packages\_soundfile_data\COPYING
22262 WARNING: Can not get binary dependencies for file: c:\users\path\to\app\venv\lib\site-packages\_soundfile_data\COPYING
22262 WARNING:   Reason: 'DOS Header magic not found.'
```

**INSTALLED PACKAGES**:

- note that `cffi`, `sounddevice`, and `setuptools` are present, as specified by the requirements. `portaudio` is not listed, but I assumed it is included in `sounddevice`, like the docs say (?)

```
(venv) λ pip list            
Package        Version       
-------------- ---------     
altgraph       0.16.1              
certifi        2019.6.16     
cffi           1.12.3        
chardet        3.0.4         
Click          7.0           
Flask          1.1.1         
Flask-WTF      0.14.2        
future         0.17.1        
idna           2.8           
itsdangerous   1.1.0         
Jinja2         2.10.1        
MarkupSafe     1.1.1         
numpy          1.17.0        
pefile         2019.4.18     
pip            19.2.2        
pycparser      2.19          
pydub          0.23.1        
PyInstaller    3.5           
pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0         
requests       2.22.0        
setuptools     41.0.1        
sounddevice    0.3.13        
SoundFile      0.10.2        
urllib3        1.25.3        
waitress       1.3.0         
Werkzeug       0.15.5        
wheel          0.33.4        
WTForms        2.2.1
```

Answer (score 2):

I managed to solve this issue without making any changes to the sounddevice source code. This is useful to me so I don't have to remember that my source code of sounddevice is hacked.

I used sounddevice 0.4.3 and it is looking for the DLL in several different locations.

I was able to trick it into finding the DLL by copying the dll under a different name and folder like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil    

# copy the sounddevice dll under a different name and path
infile = Path('../pyenv/Lib/site-packages/_sounddevice_data/portaudio-binaries/libportaudio64bit.dll')
outfile = Path('dist/bin/libportaudio-2.dll')
outfile.parent.mkdir()
shutil.copy(infile,outfile)
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat embarrassed by this, but I wasn't including the needed port audio .dlls in the build. Copying them to the `env\site-packages` and updating `sounddevice.py` to point to the correct `.dll` worked for me

---

EDITS

The pre-built dlls can be found at: https://github.com/spatialaudio/portaudio-binaries

I added them to a `/bin` directory and updated `sounddevice.py` to use them (code below)

---

Here's my updated `sounddevice.py` from v0.3.13 (manual changes marked by #!)

```
import atexit as _atexit
import os as _os
import platform as _platform
import sys as _sys
from ctypes.util import find_library as _find_library
from _sounddevice import ffi as _ffi


#! built path to my dlls (in my `bin` dir)
#! use _platform.architecture to infer whether to use 32 or 64-bit dll
try:
    _libname = 'libportaudio' + _platform.architecture()[0] + '.dll'
    _libname = _os.path.join('bin', _libname)
    _lib = _ffi.dlopen(_libname)
except OSError:
    if _platform.system() == 'Windows':  #! use Windows, not default 'Darwin'
        _libname = 'libportaudio' + _platform.architecture()[0] + '.dll'
    else:
        #! custom error
        raise OSError('PortAudio library not found! Make sure the system is Windows 64 or 32 bit and you have the '
                      'correct libportaudio dll saved in  site-packages')

#! keep rest the same
```

---

When setting up my dev environment, I run this bat script to update the default `sounddevice.py` in the virtual env with my custom one:

```
echo Updating sounddevice.py ...
copy .\sounddevice.py .\venv\Lib\site-packages\sounddevice.py /y
copy .\libportaudio32bit.dll .\venv\Lib\site-packages\libportaudio32bit.dll /y
copy .\libportaudio64bit.dll .\venv\Lib\site-packages\libportaudio64bit.dll /y
```

---

Tip: Make sure you lock the sounddevice version (in `requirements.txt` for example) so future versions don't break this hack

Comment: I am having this problem. Could you please elaborate in more detail about where you found the .dlls to copy into that `env\site-packages` folder and how exactly you updated `sounddevice.py` to point to the `.dll`  That would be greatly appreciated.  I've seen other similar questions posted with no resolution.

Answer (score 0):

I packed libportaudio32bit.dll into my exe file, and deleted these codes:

```
# import _sounddevice_data
# _libname = _os.path.join(
#     next(iter(_sounddevice_data.__path__)), 'portaudio-binaries', _libname)
_lib = _ffi.dlopen(_libname)
```

in sounddevice.py, and now it is working.

Comment: Where did you get that .dll and how did you pack it into the exe?  Much thanks for any further elaboration.