# Sounddevice: portaudio library not found

Tags: python-3.x, portaudio, python-sounddevice

Pretty much like this question: [PortAudio library not found by sounddevice during runtime [WINDOWS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57465230/portaudio-library-not-found-by-sounddevice-during-runtime-windows).

The python script worked perfectly fine but when i packaged it into executable program using pyinstaller, it returned `OSError: PortAudio library not found`.
So i go look for portaudio.dll following the answer the link above provided.

The only .dll file i can find that is related to portaudio is `libportaudio64bit.dll` which was originally under `E:\python\Lib\site-packages\_sounddevice_data\portaudio-binaries`.

[Question] : I am not sure if that is what i need.And if it is ,where should i put it?

[Note] : I tried to put it in `\env\Lib\site-packages`folder and re-packaged it.Still returned OSError.

Comment: You should probably create an issue at https://github.com/spatialaudio/python-sounddevice/issues. Please include information on how exactly you created the executable with PyInstaller.

Comment: Here's a work-around (but there should be a better solution at some point!): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57438669/